# Conda: Package missing in current win-64 channels

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm new to python and anaconda, so please excuse any ignorance.

I'm trying to install keras using conda. I'm on windows 10 (win-64). [I see that there's a win-64 package of keras @ 1.0.8](https://anaconda.org/jaikumarm/keras), but when I go to install it, `conda install -c jaikumarm keras=1.0.8`, I get the following error:

```
conda install -c jaikumarm keras=1.0.8
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .


PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - keras 1.0.8*

You can search for packages on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda keras
```

When I search using the cli:

```
anaconda search -t conda keras
Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
Run 'anaconda show <USER/PACKAGE>' to get more details:
Packages:
     Name                      |  Version | Package Types   | Platforms
     ------------------------- |   ------ | --------------- | ---------------
     CCXD/keras                |    1.1.1 | conda           | linux-64
     KEHANG/keras              |    1.0.8 | conda           | linux-64
                                          : Deep Learning for Python
     SentientPrime/keras       |    0.3.0 | conda           | linux-64, osx-64
                                          : Theano-based Deep Learning library
     alchayward/keras          |    0.1.2 | conda           | osx-64
                                          : Theano-based Deep Learning library
     alejandrito/keras         |    0.1.2 | conda           | linux-64, linux-32, osx-64
     anaconda/keras            |    1.1.1 | conda           | linux-64
     calex/keras               |    1.0.4 | conda           | osx-64
                                          : Deep Learning for Python
     conda-forge/keras         |    1.0.7 | conda           | linux-64, win-32, win-64, osx-64
     creditx/keras             |    1.1.0 | conda           | linux-64
     d_sivets/keras            |    1.0.6 | conda           | linux-64
     ddboline/keras            |   v0.0.1 | conda           | linux-64
     derickl/keras             |    1.1.1 | conda           | osx-64
     ericmjl/keras             |    0.3.1 | conda           | linux-64, osx-64
                                          : Theano-based Deep Learning library
     fbreuer/keras             |    1.0.5 | conda           | linux-64, osx-64
     jaikumarm/keras           |    1.0.8 | conda           | linux-64, win-32, win-64, linux-32, osx-64
                                          : Deep Learning for Python
     jori/keras                |    1.0.5 | conda           | osx-64
     kundajelab/keras          |    0.3.2 | conda           | linux-64, osx-64
                                          : Deep Learning for Python
     magonser/keras            |    0.3.1 | conda           | osx-64
                                          : Theano-based Deep Learning library
     markusli/keras            |    0.3.0 | conda           | linux-64
                                          : Theano-based Deep Learning library
     moutai/keras              |    1.0.6 | conda           | linux-64
     omnia/keras               |    0.3.2 | conda           | linux-64
                                          : Theano-based Deep Learning library
     richlewis/keras           |    0.3.0 | conda           | osx-64
                                          : Theano-based Deep Learning library
     wemeneker/keras           |    1.0.5 | conda           | linux-64
Found 23 packages
```

Comment: jaikumarm's channel only provides some keras versions for windows, the 1.0.8 version is only packaged for linux. You could contribute the latest version to conda-forge https://github.com/conda-forge/keras-feedstock. Folks at conda-forge are very welcoming and help if there's question/problems.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Is there a way for me to tell which version is available for which os's?

Comment: you can check anaconda.org and click through the files section of the individual channels. I'm not sure that there's a simpler way. see: https://anaconda.org/search?q=keras

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue, you need to get the latest package from anaconda website, then copy the display command and execute it in anaconda prompt window. I have posted the details in step by step [on my personal site](https://web.archive.org/web/20170523130432/http://www.mostafaelzoghbi.com/2017/04/how-to-install-keras-on-windows-10-64.html).

Comment: Tried out the link posted and still received ` Packages missing in current channels:...`

Answer (score 0):

from the search result you provided, it seems that jaikumarm/keras has win64 platform software, you can type

```
anaconda show jaikumarm/keras
```

and conda will prompt out the install channel and command for you